# Global View-Context in Django App

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Currently I've a class which I call in every single view for some global context variables which I use in my templates. It looks like this:

```
class WikiContext():
    def getWikiContext(self, view, request):
        context = {
            'app': request.resolver_match.app_name,
            'controller': view.__class__.__module__.split('.')[-1],
            'action': view.__class__.__name__.lower(),
            'categories': CategoryModel.objects.all()
        }

        return context
```

I call it like this in every single view:

```
context = WikiContext().getWikiContext(self, request)
```

**Is it possible to make it a little less code?** I don't wanna repeat the call in every single view if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [a context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors). It will be automatically loaded when the template is rendered. Therefore, there is no need to make a request in each view.

Comment: Ty, helped me a lot. Do you know how I can get my view object there. I wanna return the currently called view (class) and their method.

Comment: @bonblow I read the comments below. Sorry, I did not see what methods you use. Can you save this object in a session? I'm not sure that storing objects in a session is a good practice, but I think that this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in context processors.  Do something like:

```
def wiki_context_processor(request):
    return {
        'app': request.resolver_match.app_name,
        'controller': view.__class__.__module__.split('.')[-1],
        'action': view.__class__.__name__.lower(),
        'categories': CategoryModel.objects.all()
    }
```

Then you can add it to the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your settings.py file:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'myproject.context_processors.wiki_context_processor',
)
```

Comment: Yes I did after Nuchimik told me about context processors. Currently I don't know how I get the view object there. Do you know? Ty

Comment: What do you mean?  That context should be added to every view.

Comment: "view.__class__.__module__.split('.')[-1]," I can't call this in my context_processor, because "view" object doesn't exist there.

Comment: I see.  I didn't pay attention to the magic methods you were using.  I'm not sure how to access those in the context processor.